# Format User-Input Data in DataGridView Cell

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, string-formatting

I am creating a DataGridView object in VB.Net which has a few columns where the users can enter the data.  I would like the data value input by the user to be formatted as currency once the user has submitted their input (I have data validation already set up and working).

Essentially if I put the value `1800.56` in the Cell, I want it so format to `$1,800.56`.

I've tried this and it doesn't seem to work:

```
Private Sub dg_CellEndEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dg.CellEndEdit
    dg.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = String.Format(dg.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value, "c")
End Sub
```

This should work should it not?  Yet my input stays as the un-formatted input.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the value (you could do it like that too, but...), you should be setting column defaultcellstyle (formatting) instead, or per cell.

Comment: You see this is why this problem confuses me.  When I create the column I **do** set the `DefaultCellStyle` with the following line of code: `dg.Columns("Cost").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c"`

Comment: try `dg.Columns("Cost").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C2"` The 2 being the number of decimal places.